# Почему статус nginx inactive?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, администрирование, sudo

Добрый день, развернул вдс (ubuntu 16.3) прописываю у себя в консоли :

```
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
```

далее

```
sudo ufw status
```

но статус пишет как неактивный
почему?

Пробовал и рут и обычного юзера с судо

p.s маны отсюда брал [клик](https://www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-nginx-v-ubuntu-16-04/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

программа *ufw* пишет «inatcive» не про программу *nginx*, а про своё собственное состояние: «не включена».

для «включения» выполните команду:

```
$ sudo ufw enable
```